# Databases sync through webservice

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql-server-ce

I Do not know much about it, but I have a question and I hope you can help me if it is possible.

I need to synchronize two databases, one is a mobile database (SQL Server Compact) and the other a MySQL database. Both have exactly the same tables.

Then, is it possible to synchronize the records via a webservice?

I accept any ideas, suggestions or help.

Many greetings and thanks.

pd: sorry about my english... :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [SymmetricDS](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/). It runs as a webservice (tomcat6) and is able to do both one and two way synchronization. It also supports the concept of a single root node and several client nodes.

SymmetridDS is database "transparent", meaning that it can synchronize between databases independent of database type.

It's quick, stable and reliable. The learning curve might be a bit steep when you first dive into it, but it is quite a piece of software once you get the hang of it!

Answer (score 1):

yes.

you need to create a piece of code that can connect to both databases at the same time.

you need to then read them and decide what is different between the two,

then you need to apply changes that make one look more like the other (non-trivial).

You will need to decide which one should be the master, or if both should modify the other somehow.